# Creating a list of items with different tags + filter

Tags: javascript, html, list, filter

I have prepared an example what I would like to produce: [link](http://kod.djpw.cz/rsnb).
I have already looked for something and I have found the way to create a filter but just for one value... In my case I need more values all together combined. So that if I wanted a flat in Prague 1 and for a price less than 6 000 000, it would filter it for me.

How could I achieve it? Thank you very much for response.

Comment: Please provide the code you are working on.

Comment: As per the link you have, are there any restrictions on using javascript? or you want to achieve it using CSS only?

Comment: Pratik - 
No restrictions at all ! No problem for me to use JS, but unfortunatelly I do not know how to use it...


kevin - link is in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the codePen I have created for you with example:

```js
$('#filter').click(function() {
  var _typeFilter = $('input[name=type]:checked').val();
  var _locationFilter = $('input[name=location]:checked').val();

  $('ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).filter('[type=' + _typeFilter + ']').filter('[location=' + _locationFilter + ']').length > 0)
      $(this).show();
    else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});

$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('ul li').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="flat" />Flat
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="house" />House
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="location" value="city1" />City1
  <input type="radio" name="location" value="city2" />City2
  <input type="radio" name="location" value="city3" />City3
</div>
<a href="#" id="filter">Filter</a>
<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>

<ul>
  <li location='city1' type='flat' price='500000'>Item1</li>
  <li location='city1' type='house' price='300000'>Item2</li>
  <li location='city2' type='flat' price='400000'>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXeEgO)

You should use Jquery to achieve this. Bind parameters with attributes of your 
'li' tag and filter them using Jquery.

Comment: I created the selector for items but button CLEAR doesnt work properly.

Comment: [link](http://bastard.php5.cz/buy.html) here it is. Second thing I need is that in options I wan to have for example 3 prices, but Items wont have the same price as in otions, but lesser (e.g.- property for 29 000 would react for the filter - less than 30 000 and so)

Comment: Well in that case you can filter using .filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("Price") < _priceFilter;
});

Comment: wonderful! :) but the #clear doesnt work on the website i don't know why...
can we create another button to order filtered items on raising price? like the lowest price would be on top (and vice versa)

Comment: can you look at the web yourself? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cth0oaeycmpwhjs/web.rar?dl=0) why buttons dont work.. Can you add the dropdown for filtering the content (from cheapest to most expansive). I would be happy to invite you for a coffee (via paypal), if you help me out.

Comment: two mistakes in your code. (1) Remove id "filter" from your <div> tag (2) change $('.items li').show() in your clear function. check updated code here [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOeKxm)

Comment: and yeah, code also contains your desirable price based sorting filter. enjoy ;)

Comment: can you change radio inputs to radio at TYPE and LOCATIONS, so the customer could choose to view houses and flats simultaneously?

Comment: Hi, cannot code everything like this for you, as this site doesn't hold that purpose. Understand the jquery and concepts and you will be able to do that, good luck :)

Comment: I would certainly love to do it myself, however, now it is impossible for me to catch up with time. I need it till tomorrow, as I mentioned before, I would be happy to pay you. Can we meet online to chat? facebook.com/alxemist